# PHP MySQL Counting Multiple Columns in single table

Tags: php, mysql, database, optimization, count

I'm trying to count different columns in a single table and store them as variables in PHP, I don't think I should be doing it this way I don't think:

```
$dog_count = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM animals WHERE animal='dog'"));
$cat_count = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM animals WHERE animal='cat'"));
$parrot_count...
```

I'm thinking there is probably a better way to count statistics. Any advice?

Thanks :)

Comment: Another question, say we had 10 million rows in the database, would it still be okay to COUNT() every minute? Would it be better to have a summary table? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get all the aminals and their respective counts in one query:

```
SELECT animal, COUNT(*) AS AnimalCount
    FROM animals
    GROUP BY animal
```

Comment: Sorry for the basic questions, how would I go about putting the count into a variable, $cat_count, $dog_count, etc?